# tmux hangs when re-attaching session after logout

Tags: macos, command-line, macports, tmux

Since Yosemite, my [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net), which I installed via MacPorts, "hangs" when I re-attach it after my user has logged out and logged in again. I.e. it cannot start new processes, like a new command line. The logs in console do not show anything.

I do not even know how I start to figure out what's happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the use of `__DARWIN_VERS_1050` in the [*tmux* Portfile](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/tmux/Portfile?rev=132518#L28) may be causing this.

If you are able, try a clean compile from source (i.e. without that CPPFLAGS addition). Be sure to completely restart your *tmux* server using your fresh-built binary (the difference happens in the daemon(3) call made when the server first starts up—so using a “clean” binary to connect to a server started with the MacPorts-built binary would not help).

---

Tangentially, since you use *tmux* on OS X, you might also use my [*reattach-to-user-namespace*](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) wrapper program. It seems like the wrapper program may not actually be necessary on Yosemite for pasteboard access inside *tmux*. If you are using the wrapper (and you do not mind testing a bit), try removing it from your configuration on your Yosemite system. I would appreciate hearing whether things (continue) to work without use of the wrapper (or whether you still lose pasteboard access at some point).

Comment: Great. I will try it out. I already found your wrapper program, but was unsure what I would need it for.

Comment: @Arne: You can probably ignore the wrapper since it looks like you may not need it under Yosemite. Good luck with the cleanly built *tmux*.

Comment: Johnson: It works. I have successfully rebuilt tmux with the augmented Portfile. I will file a ticket with MacPorts, and be happy for the time being.